# Changing the font of Eprint fields in biblatex

Tags: fonts, biblatex

I would like to have Eprint information displayed in my bibliography, but in the same font as the surrounding text. Changing the `verbatim` font for the document apparently does not accomplish this.

Here is a minimum working example demonstrating the problem. the `\verb|text|` command within the document appears in `\rmfamily` as it should, but the arXiv pre-print information in the bibliography still appears in `\ttfamily`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{paper,
Author = {Some One},
Title = {Important things},
Journal = {A.~Reput.~J.},
Year = {2000},
Eprint = {1234.5678},
Eprintclass = {fa.KE},
Eprinttype = {arXiv}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\rmfamily}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
One paper is \cite{paper}, and some verbatim text is
\verb|arXiv:1234.5678 [fa.KE]|.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This results in the following output, with the arXiv reference in the main text appearing in `\rmfamily` even though it was typeset with the `\verb` command, but the same text in the bibliography still in `\ttfamily`:
[image: Output of MWE]

How can I change the font used to display Eprint records in a `biblatex` bibliography?

Answer (score 9):

My first thought was that `\urlstyle{same}` should be sufficient, but it turned out that a few hardcoded instances of `\texttt` had to be removed as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\rmfamily}
\makeatother

\urlstyle{same}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  arXiv\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
       \nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
     {}
%    {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
     {\addspace\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}
     \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
       {}
%       {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
       {\addspace\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{paper,
Author = {Some One},
Title = {Important things},
Journal = {A.~Reput.~J.},
Year = {2000},
Eprint = {1234.5678},
Eprintclass = {fa.KE},
Eprinttype = {arXiv}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
One paper is \cite{paper}, and some verbatim text is
\verb|arXiv: 1234.5678 [fa.KE]|.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly in the MWE (and in fact the redefinition of the \verbatim@font is no longer needed) but it turns out that if you also use the hyperref package, it stops working and the following error is generated: `Undefined control sequence. http://arxiv.org/\abx  @arxivpath/1234.5678 \end {document}`. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @MichaelUnderwood Because I forgot to add `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`.

Comment: Aah, thank you! That was the first thing I thought of, but I tried putting it inside the `\DeclareFieldFormat` command and for whatever reason that doesn't solve the problem.